# Encoding type for polish characters

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have json string which is having characters which exist in polish. example below

**"Reno Truck Lachowski & Łuczak - NAPRAWY CHŁODNI,IZOTERM,ZABUDÓW POJAZDÓW CIĘŻAROWYCH"**

or

**"RENO TRUCK Lachowski & Łuczak s.c. SERWIS POJAZDÓW UZYTKOWYCH"**

I need to update this value in database .

Can anyone let me know what is encoding type i need to set..

I tried with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, but both doesn't work .

Observed that when i set ISO-8859-1 the value seems to different as below

**"RENO TRUCK Lachowski & ?uczak s.c. SERWIS POJAZDÓW UZYTKOWYCH"**

The character Ł doesn't get updated.

Can anyone help please..

Comment: Hi Akil, can you confirm which database product are you using, the encoding configured on the database and if you are forcing eny encoding on the JDBC connection string?

Comment: Hi @JorgeLuisGarciaPerez : I am using sybase database, I have set encoding on connector configuration has jdbc:jtds:sybase://user:port/dabase;user=gggggg;password=ppppp;charset=ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

JSON values are expected to be encoded in UTF-8. The string you quoted seems to be encoded in something else. You are expected to know the encoding of the data. Note that it may not be a valid JSON if it is not UTF-8. Once you know it you could use DataWeave to convert the encoding to what your database is expect. Based on the JDBC URL it seems that the database connection is expecting ISO-8859-1.